# Uploading an image giving "Not a DICOM Stream" from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Am facing a wired issue when I am trying to upload and image(Dicom type) through JMeter.

Steps:

1. Login to the application
2. Upload the image(dicom type).

From Browser I am able to upload the same image successfully. Only thing worrying is from browser I can see some encrypted data in the request payload.

## Browser Request Details:

RequestHeader:

[image]

[image]

Request Payload:

[image]

## Jmeter Details

Error:
[image]

JMeter Configuration:
[image]

[image]

Header Manager:

[image]

Somehow this is not working, please let me know if I miss any information?

## updated section

when recorded with script recorder,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully upload the image using browser why don't you just record the associated request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder?](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

The only extra thing you will need to do is to copy the file you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation - this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information:

- [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
- [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: thanx Dmitri, I tried with that as well. check my updated comment. Dont know how to handle the request payload with that encrypted data